# Query performance of SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I am trying to know the best possible way to improve performance of a query given to me by my client. It contains a few tables which are joined and one of table is called `dwh.fac_sale_detail` which contains 1.5 billion rows.

This table `dwh.fac_sale_detail` is partitioned based on one of its columns called `TradingDateKey`. It actually stores data in `yyyymmdd` format but it is of `INT` datatype.

This has `TradingDateKeys` from 2005 to 2015. But the partitions are created until year 2014 only.

One of the guys in another team adviced the following and I am trying to follow his advice but I am new to creating or altering of partitions and do not know if this actually makes any difference to improve query performance :

what he said in his own words is

> *The FactSalesDetail table is currently about 1.5 Billion Rows and is currently partitioned on TradingDate into 10 partitions by year with about 150 Million Rows per partition. It would be a good idea to further partition the latest year into monthly partitions and apply a columnstore index on all the partitions. Applying the index on each partition will be a once-off and you should only need to maintain the index for the current partition going forward.*

Please find attached screenshots I can provide for better understanding:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your question? If you want to know if partitioning will give you better performance, you have to look at the queries and query plans. Maybe you are missing an index, type mismatch, or have problems with Parameter Sniffing etc.

Comment: Hi Peer, thanks for your reply. i want to improve query performance and if i provide you the actual execution plan ,will it possible for you provide me suggestions on improving the performance?

Comment: Does partitioning really have any effect on performance? If you put the partitions on different physical hard drives you might get better IO when selecting over several partitions. But do you really want your database spread over 20 physical drives?

Comment: hi Adrian, i do not know whether i have to create partitions on that large table (fac_sale_Detail) to improve performance . but the query just took 1:39:09 and it returns 643271 rows of data. any idea how can i give you the actual execution plan?

Comment: @Deepak only if you provide the query and execution plan we can say something about what is possibly going on.

Comment: Peer, how do i share the actual execution plan with you?please suggest!

Comment: Hi Peer,  Please click in the following dropbox link so that you can get my execution.sqlplan file https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7522f20w3vemqu/estimate.sqlplan?dl=0 Kindly check ,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample table and used Create Partition wizard which comes on the context menu of the SQL database table

I take following script as output

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [TradingDatePartitionFunction](int) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (N'20151201', N'20151101', N'20151001', N'20150901', N'20150801', N'20150701', N'20150601', N'20150501', N'20150401', N'20150301', N'20150201', N'20150101', N'20140101')
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [DatePartitionScheme] AS PARTITION [TradingDatePartitionFunction] TO (
[file1], [file2], [..], [..], [..], [..], [..], 
[..], [..], [..], [..], [..], [..], [..]
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_DatePartitionScheme_635780868545743751] ON [dbo].[sale_detail]
(
    [TradingDateKey]
) ON [DatePartitionScheme]([TradingDateKey])
DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_DatePartitionScheme_635780868545743751] ON [dbo].[sale_detail]
```

After partitions are created, then inserted data are placed in correct partition files

You can refer to following [table partition](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-partition-table-non-partitioned-table-sql-server-2008.aspx) sample and more on the web
But it is a good idea to keep old nearly historical data in one partition, and other frequently read recent data into different partitions in smaller amount of numbers.
If you check my partition function, I defined 12 monthly partitions, 1 for last year (for 2014) and one for previous years

I'm adding following codes after your comment about this answer Deepak

First you need to add new file groups for additional partitions using

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME DatePartitionScheme NEXT USED [fileN]
```

Please refer to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190347%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Then for adding new partitions you can use SPLIT as follows

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [TradingDatePartitionFunction]() 
SPLIT RANGE ('20151201')
```

You need to run above for each distinguishing value for the partition function. Split will use the next unused file for the new created partition

If you want to merge or combine two partitions together, you can use

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [TradingDatePartitionFunction]() 
MERGE RANGE ('20140101')
```

You can check the result of your statements using following code

```
select r.* 
from sys.partition_range_values r
inner join sys.partition_functions f
on f.function_id = r.function_id
where f.name = 'TradingDatePartitionFunction'
```

I hope this guides you for a solution,
Please test before applying on a productive environment

Comment: thanks eralper , your answer is much appreciated,my table is already partioned from 2005 untill 2014-06-30, and it already has clustered index on tradingdatekey too. how do i extend the partition until 2015 and i want to do this monthly as you shown above.thanks

Comment: Thanks Eralper, ill try in DEV environment and will see the results. by the way how can i share the actual execution plan with you?.

Comment: Just want to add that splitting the non-empty partition in this case will be a very expensive operation.  Consider rebuilding with `CREATE INDEX...WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)`.